# How to achieve Mysql Union with left joins on two tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, union

There is a deposit table

[image]

Then there is a withdraw table

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uVwg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uVwg.png)]

I have to create a mysql query so that i have columns
userid, name, email, total deposit, total withdraw and net (total deposit - total withdraw)
for a given date range from the above two tables
with status as Approved
Ordered by on the basis of net

There will be records in withdraw table but no records in deposit table for a userid then total withdraw is 0 for that corresponding period
and vice versa
if there are records in deposit table but no records in withdraw table for a userid then for such users the total withdraw is 0 for that corresponding period

How to achieve this with MYSQL query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, prepare a dataset that is the UNION of your two tables, but just including the 'Approved' records:

```sql
SELECT *, 'deposit' AS type FROM deposit WHERE status = 'Approved'
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'withdraw' AS type FROM withdraw WHERE status = 'Approved'
```

Then you can select from this dataset, with some conditional sums:

```sql
WITH alltypes AS (
    SELECT *, 'deposit' AS type FROM deposit WHERE status = 'Approved'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'withdraw' AS type FROM withdraw WHERE status = 'Approved'
)
SELECT
    userid,
    name,
    email,
    SUM(if(type = 'deposit', amount, 0)) AS 'total deposit',
    SUM(if(type = 'withdraw', amount, 0)) AS 'total withdraw',
    SUM(if(type = 'deposit', amount, -1 * amount)) AS 'net'
FROM alltypes
GROUP BY userid, name, email
```

This gives:

```
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+----------------+------+
| userid | name | email         | total deposit | total withdraw | net  |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+----------------+------+
|      1 | fine | fine@fine.com |           500 |             50 |  450 |
|      4 | new  | new@new.com   |            20 |             30 |  -10 |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+----------------+------+
```

Comment: Many Many thanks sir. Also should I put the created_at date range critieria in the union as well? Meaning lets say only november records of deposit and withdraw tables are to be selected. That is, only november deposit, withdraw and net is to be found.

Comment: Yes, you could put any additional constraints on the records before you UNION them